# Unable to handle kernel paging request at X while intercepting the system call

Tags: c, linux, kernel-module, kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux Kernel: System call hooking example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103315/linux-kernel-system-call-hooking-example)

I have been trying to hook the system calls at the kernel level.I got the basic idea from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103315/linux-kernel-system-call-hooking-example).The system call I was trying to intercept was the **fork()**. So I found out the address of the **sys_call_table** from System.map and it turned out to be 0xc12c9e90.Now I wrote the module as below.

```
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/unistd.h>
#include<linux/semaphore.h>
#include<asm/cacheflush.h>
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
void **sys_call_table;
unsigned long addr;
asmlinkage int (*original_call)(struct pt_regs);
asmlinkage int our_call(struct pt_regs regs)
{
        printk("Intercepted sys_fork");
        return original_call(regs);
}
static int __init p_entry(void)
{
        struct page *pg;
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Module Intercept inserted");
        sys_call_table=(void *)0xc12c9e90;
        pg=virt_to_page(sys_call_table);
        addr=(unsigned long)page_address(pg);
        set_memory_rw(addr,1);
        original_call=sys_call_table[__NR_fork];
        sys_call_table[__NR_fork]=our_call;
        set_memory_ro(addr,1);
        return 0;
}
static void __exit p_exit(void)
{
        sys_call_table[__NR_fork]=original_call;
        set_memory_ro(addr,1);
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Module Intercept removed");
}
module_init(p_entry);
module_exit(p_exit);
```

I compiled the module and tried to insert it to the kernel.Unfortunately the dmesg output gave me a message as follows **BUG:unable to handle kernel paging request at c12c9e98** and here is the ellaborate dmesg out put

[image]
[image]

As an experiment to find out the problem, I simply commented out the line

```
 sys_call_table[__NR_fork]=our_call;
```

After that I repeated the compilation and followed by insertion.And it didn't show up any errors. So I concluded that ,the above specified line which assigns the new function in to sys_call_table is the problem. But I don't know what could be causing it and how to solve it.Can any one help me out to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that your call to `set_memory_rw` isn't taking effect because you do not use `flush_tlb`, so the TLB of the CPU is still active when your write to the `syscall_table` takes effect. You need to flush the TLB. You can probably use `local_flush_tlb()`.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work :(