# How to run code every time a new socket is created on my Linux machine?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, tcp

I need to call a function every time a new TCP socket is created at my Linux server. The schema code is:

```
do {
    new_socket = block_until_new_socket_created();
    do_something(new_socket);
} while (true);
```

The question is, is there any library/tool/function to be notified when a new tcp socket is created at the UNIX/Linux server where the code is being executed?

The programming code is C.

Comment: How I call the process identifier of the socket descriptor. Sorry if it was not clear.

Comment: I don't understand what it even means.

Comment: Where is your code supposed to run? In the server process? On the same machine? What is a socket pid? What information do you want to get exactly?

Comment: trojanfoe: when a new tcp socket is created at the system, usually there is a process sending/receiving bytes through this socket, and every process running on a system requires an identifier.

Comment: But that information isn't transmitted across the TCP/IP protocol, so there is no way to retrieve it.

Comment: what I name socket pid (abbreviation of "process id"), is the process identifier of the process sending/receiving through a specific socket.

Comment: Just need a library or tool to be notified when a new tcp socket is created. That is the question posted. Taking the pid is something I've already done.

Comment: you can do this from kernel side without changing it's source code. If you have privileges to load a module to kernel on your server, then you can use kprobes to probe an internal kernel function, which creates new socket. But this might be too much (though it might be easier than it sounds ;) ).

Comment: *zoska*'s approach points in direction of an answer. Reopening this question would allow an answer.

Comment: Thanks Flow for the edition.

Comment: @tremendows there is no such library.

Comment: @nos proving the absence of a Linux library seems like a rather difficult task

Answer (score 6):

Old question, but there is at least two ways to do this:

1) Use the audit subsystem

You can configure auditd and the Linux audit subsystem to log a message every time any syscall happens.  It will include the timestamp and the calling process.  Something that hooks 'connect()' and/or 'bind()' should get you what you need for sockets.  This is what auditd was designed to do.

2) Use ip_conntrack (netfilter/ip_tables)

Use something like the libnetfilter-conntrack library (which uses the ip_conntrack kernel module) will get you notifications of all new sockets with filtering as desired.  However, it will only tell you local and remote address/port and timestamp, not inode.  Which means to correlate this back to a pid, you have to first read the notification from conntrack, and then parse the files in /proc/net/{tcp/udp/whatever} files to find the socket and the inode, and then parse all the /proc/$pid/fd/* files to find out which pid owns that inode. 
At each step, you have to hope the socket hasn't gone away by the time you read the files in that three-step process.  Such a system is used by flowtop from the netsniff-ng utils package.

All systems require root, although once auditd is configured by root, the logs can be read by non-root if you want. I'd think you'd want to use auditd whenever possible.  The ip_conntrack interface seems a bit nicer at first, but auditd gets you all the information you want, including pid tracking, for free.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know if this is possible in "normal programs", but you could write an own kernel module that "hooks" the associated system call that is called if a socket is created (I think it is `sys_socket`, but I am not sure about this). But as @Zoska points out, you need the priviledge to load kernel modules.

"Hooking" means (basically) that you redirect the original call to your own custom function that - in turn - can call the *original* system call and perform operations before and afterwards so that you can let your function notify your program. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103315/linux-kernel-system-call-hooking-example) are some information on system call hooking.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get a notification for socket creation. What you can do is periodically check the sockets that are open by reading `/proc/net/tcp`. One of the columns in that file is the "inode" of the socket.

Once you have the inode you can find the *processes* (there can be several) that have that socket open by scanning through the `/proc/[pid]/fd` directories.

Comment: A kind of notification could be got using network sniffer like libpcap. Attach to all interfaces and track packets with SYN flags. Getting SYN+ACK means either connect success for a client side or temporary allocation for a server side (and ongoing ACK finalizes it). This isn't exactly _socket_ creation case but connection creation case, but could be useful for the topic starter too.

Answer (score 0):

Well you should be able to use nmap to see the available open sockets on your linux machine. For example, if you happen to create and bind a server to a port number, say 9999, nmap will show that port is open.

I don't think getting PID is possible for a socket-server... However, you could get the PID of the program using that socket by using the 'top' command.

Answer (score 0):

If the sockets of interest are managed by inetd, then you may be able to modify it to trigger your events when it accepts a new connection.

If, however, you also want out going sockets and those that bypass inetd, you will need to use the approaches proposed in the other answers.