# Get notifications for socket events in kernel

Tags: linux, sockets, audit, selinux

I need to find for local tcp-connections/Unix-domain-connections the client process that starts the connection in the most effective way possible.

I currently have a solution for this implemented in a driver, that intercept both accept and connect syscalls, match them, and finds out the client process.

Now I try to achieve the same **without my own** driver.

**Different approaches I tried:**

- Linux auditing system plugin that intercept the appropriate syscalls and resolve the client in a similar manner. This method has 3 problems:

  1. Each intercepted event flows from the kernel to the auditd process to some other intermediate process and only than to my plugin.
  2. The audit rules are applies for all the plugins and audit-log - I can't define my own set of filtering rules. - which may cause on machines that uses the audit system for extreme inefficiency.
  3. It requires that audit to be installed on the machine (which is not default for many Linux distributions).
- Imitate netstat/lsof - In order to find the process that holds a connection, they iterate the entire procfs mount - this makes sense, because after connection establishment, each connection could belongs to more than one process.
  This approach is extremely not effective if I want to do so for each connection establishment.
- I thought to try one of the LSM (Linux security modules) solutions - but I am currently unfamiliar with it - Is their a LSM that can pass the kernel events for a running application for a "decision"?

I will be happy to hear suggestions and other comments that could lead me to a reasonable solution for my original goal.

Comment: netfilter, iptables/nftables.

Comment: I already have a mechanism to get notifications for newly estabilshed connections. What I lack is their initiator, and according to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23532240/2835437) I would still have to iterate the entire procfs mount to get that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Look at the source address of the SYN packet, it's the initiator.

Comment: I need the client process id..

Comment: A long time ago, iptables had an "owner" match. IDK what's the current recommended replacement for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an option that suits my needs for Unix-domain-sockets only - if runnning code in the server side is a possability (as in my case) one can use getsockopt in the following manner:

```
getsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PEERCRED, &cr, &len)
```

More details in http://welz.org.za/notes/on-peer-cred.html