# How to use the function from a custom kernel module?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, system-calls, kernel-module, archlinux

**I have successfully implemented a custom syscall `getpuid()`, and now I need to write a custom dynamically loadable module to export a function which has exactly the same functionality of the custom system call `getpeuid()`.** This syscall is used to get the euid of the calling process's parent process. And the segment of the custom module:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/printk.h>
#include <linux/rcupdate.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/cred.h>

static int *getpeuid(pid_t pid, uid_t *uid)
{
    // Code to get the parent process euid
    ......;
}

EXPORT_SYMBOL(getpeuid);

/* This function is called when the module is loaded. */
int getpeuid_init(void)
{
       printk(KERN_INFO "getpeuid() loaded\n");

       return 0;
}

/* This function is called when the module is removed. */
void getpeuid_exit(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Removing getpeuid()\n");
}

/* Macros for registering module entry and exit points. */
module_init( getpeuid_init );
module_exit( getpeuid_exit );

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Return parent euid.");
MODULE_AUTHOR("CGG");
```

I have successfully compiled this custom module and insert module into the kernel. Then, I wrote a test to test the functionality of the function exported from the loadable kernel module implemented:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;
    uid_t *uid;

    uid = (uid_t *)malloc(sizeof(uid_t));

    pid = getppid();
    int retval = getpeuid(pid, uid);

    if( retval < 0 )
    {
        perror("My system call returned with an error code.");
    }

    printf("My syscall's parameters: %ld \n", pid);
    printf("My system call returned %d.\n", retval);
    printf("Current values:  uid=%ld \n", *uid);
    return 0;
}
```

But when I am compiling the test script, it gives me the following error:

> /tmp/ccV8WTx0.o: In function 'main':
>   hw5-test.c:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `supermom'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I checked the available symbols in the system using `cat /proc/kallsyms`, and the symbol I exported is there:

> fa0eb000 T getpeuid    [getpeuid]

I just don't know how am I supposed to use my custom function then, since I don't have a header file for my custom module to be included in my test script. Even if I need to write a header file, I don't know how to write a header file for custom kernel module.

Could someone give me a hand here?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

**I am only allowed to use the dynamically loadable kernel module to simulate the functionality of the syscall.**

**EDIT:**

**I am not allowed to modify the system call table in the module initialization code.**

I got the following link from others as a hint：

https://www.linux.com/learn/linux-career-center/31161-the-kernel-newbie-corner-kernel-symbols-whats-available-to-your-module-what-isnt

Comment: Your immediate problem is that you are trying to link against a C library that doesn't include support for your change - it lacks a wrapper for your custom syscall.  If you actually managed to add a new syscall, you have its number, and there's usually a C library function that will let you call an arbitrary one by number rather than name, which you could start with before you get around to modifying the C library for your modified kernel.  Of course, it still seems to be an open question if you actually accomplished adding a new syscall or not.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yeah, I have revised my question, and actually what I need to do is to add a function via loadable kernel module to simulate the behavior of a syscall I have written previously.

Comment: You cannot add a syscall without modifying the syscall table.  So either, you modified it and you need to call it by number or add a wrapper to your library, or else you didn't modify it and will have to use some other interface, or else you are wishing for things that just aren't going to happen until you spend more time learning about these realities and adjust your goals to them.  Finally, you have to stop using the word "simulate" in a meaningless fashion.  Say **exactly** what you mean.  And while you are at it, stop calling a C program a "script".

Comment: ....By simulate I mean the exported function from the module must have exactly the same functionality as the syscall I have implemented previously.

Comment: Such functionality is only exported to the kernel, not to userspace.  If you want that you will have to use one of the kernel-userspace interfaces, such as already discussed.

Comment: @JialunLiu for further research, you might want to google *"syscall interception"* and *"syscall hooking in loadable kernel module"*. Updated my answer below with a link to exploits which may (or may not) work depending upon the system setup. [Happy hacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_%28programmer_subculture%29).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use sysfs

Checkout the [list of various **Linux kernel <--> Userspace interfaces**](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/%7Earkeller/linux/kernel_user_space_howto.html).

> To allow **userspace** to interact with a **loadable kernel module**, consider using **sysfs**.

To add support for sysfs within your loadable module, checkout the basics of [a sys-fs entry](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt).

A good guide with the [best practices of creating sysfs entries](http://kroah.com/log/blog/2013/06/26/how-to-create-a-sysfs-file-correctly/) should get you started the right way.

The userspace test will then change from

```
int retval = getpeuid(pid, uid);
```

to something that uses `open`, `write()` and `read()`
to interact with the sysfs entry just like a regular file.
<sub>( Why file? because [everything is a file on UNIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file). )</sub>

You could further simplify this to using a shell-script that uses `echo`/`cat` commands to pass/gather data from the loadable kernel module via the sysfs entry.

---

#### Alternate option : A beautiful/ugly Hack

**Disclaimer:** I agree that trying to use syscalls within a loadable kernel module is neither a proper solution, nor guaranteed to always work. I know what i am doing.
<sub>(Hover the mouse over the following block, **ONLY** if you agree to the above)</sub>

> Checkout this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26794790/319204)** and related **[code](https://github.com/MrN0body/rsysadd)** that describes a potential "hack" to allow implementing custom syscalls in loadable modules in any unused locations within the current syscall table of the kernel.
>
>
>  Also carefully go through the several answers/comments to this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2103315/319204). They deal with overcoming the problem of not being able to modify the syscall table. One of the comments also emphasises the fact that hypervisors implementing their own extensions are not likely to be affected by this "exploit" as they offer better protection of the syscall table.
>
>
>  *Note that such non-standard interfaces may not always work and even if they do, they can stop working anytime. Stick to standard interfaces for reliability.*

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am only allowed to use the dynamically loadable kernel module to simulate the functionality of the syscall.

Comment: Updated the answer. For educational purposes, checkout the ugly hack section. Be careful though, you have been warned.

Comment: Sorry again, man, I am not allowed to modify the system call table in the module initialization. But thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: No problems. Any reason for such specific restrictions? Is this a code-challenge/assignment question? Please share the **original problem statement** if there is one. Someone can then help identify the *"correct answer"* the original problem statement is looking for...

Comment: Yes, it is a code challenge, I have revised my question already.

Answer (score 1):

EXPORT_SYMBOL exports the symbol within the kernel, so that other kernel modules can use it.  It will not make it available to userland programs.
Adding a new system call doesn't appear to be possible via a kernel module:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47701/adding-a-new-system-call-to-linux-3-2-x-with-a-loadable-kernel-module

Comment: @TheCodeArtist sorry, rolling back your edit.  You completely changed the meaning of my answer.

Comment: Sure. no problems. I guess i better provide a separate answer since the OP wants to call a function within a loadable kernel and going the syscall way is problematic.

Comment: @MK. Thanks for your reply, let me rephrase my question then, I have successfully implement a getpeuid syscall already. But I need to use a loadable module to simulate the function of the syscall `getpeuid()` I implemented, how am I supposed to do that?

Comment: @JialunLiu sorry, don't understand what you mean by "simulate".  If you want to add a new syscall usable from the userland, you will need to recompile the kernel.

Comment: The problem the poster is actually hitting is that the C library doesn't know anything about this customization - it's a build-time problem, not a runtime problem (yet).

Comment: @MK. I mean that the function in the dynamically loadable kernel must have the same functionality as the system call I have implemented previously -- to retrieve the euid of the calling process's parent process.