# Hook ALL system calls in Linux

Tags: linux, system-calls, entry-point, systrace

The goal is to add a hook to **all** system calls in Linux, that is, the hook function should get called before any of those 300 Linux system calls are invoked.

There are `sys_call_table` hacks (e.g. [[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103315/linux-kernel-system-call-hooking-example)]), which however only allow to hook one or few system calls; that is, if `read()` needs to be hijacked, the `sys_read` entry in `sys_call_table` is modified to the new function that has a hook handler.

Of course, you can manually hook all 300 syscall entries; but I am looking for a more elegant approach with few code modification.

A possible approach is to change the file `entry_64.S` where `ENTRY(system_call)` reside. However, as I need to use linux kernel module and hack a live system, I find it difficult to modify the memory image of `entry_64.S` in a running Linux system.

So my question is:

1. if the `entry_64.S` design makes sense, how to modify a live memory area where kernel code resides (kernel code segment)?
2. if it does not make sense, in general, how to modify one (or few) place in Linux src code and allows all sys calls being hooked.

PS: platform: Linux 3.16 and x86_64

PS2: Again my question is DIFFERENT from those `sys_call_table` hacks in prior stack overflow questions. See paragraph 2 for details.

Comment: @msw my question is different, please read OP.

Comment: @msw - if there are no answers (as in this case) then it really doesn't matter if the question is changed. Radical edits to a question only become problematic when there are answers.

Comment: @Richard Did you find an answer to your question ?

Comment: https://opensource.com/article/17/7/dynamic-tracing-linux-user-and-kernel-space