# What are parameters of sys_clone() system call and how to hook it in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux-kernel, hook

I'm using a kernel module to hook system calls like `sys_read()`, `sys_write()` and so on. The way I'm hooking it is pretty much like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103315/linux-kernel-system-call-hooking-example).

Now I want to hook `sys_clone()` in the same way. What I can find from the source code is as follows.

```
long sys_clone(unsigned long, unsigned long, int __user *, int, int __user*)
```

First I have no idea of what those parameters mean. I tried to printk them to see. However, even when I tested with a program invoking plenty of `clone()` system call, I didn't see any printings from `my_sys_clone()`. Is that because the `clone()` didn't request for `sys_clone()` I hooked at all? Or are there any special cases for hooking a `sys_clone()`?

Comment: According to man clone (http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone) `clone()` actually calls `sys_clone`. That function is defined in `kernel/fork.c` using `SYSCALL_DEFINE5(clone)`, and just calls `do_fork()`, so you can extract  parameters meaning from it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks a lot. I've read the parameters in SYSCALL_DEFINE5(clone). It's very helpful. But how does it go from sys_clone to SYSCALL_DEFINE5(clone)? Any interfaces?

Comment: `SYSCALL_DEFINE5(clone)` is actually an implementation of `sys_clone` function. As for inability to hook system call, check that you attempt to hook exactly that `clone`, which is defined as syscal: as you can see from `kernel/fork.c`, there are several compatible versions of clone, dependent of kernel's configuration.

Comment: @Tsyvarev It worked! So system calls like fork() and clone() can only be hooked through changing source code? Where can i see that SYSCALL_DEFINE5（clone）is the definition of sys_clone()?