# How to intercept not exported kernel function from loadable kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, intercept, fedora16

We use kernel 3.7 Fedora16, 64-bit and want to intercept kernel functions.

We tried [Linux Kernel: System call hooking example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103315/linux-kernel-system-call-hooking-example/39202118#39202118) and successfully received the address of "sys_call_table", while returned address of "access_remote_vm" is NULL.

Please advice.

Comment: There are many questions on Stack Overflow about replacing system calls in Linux kernel. Did you check them?

Comment: Yes we checked and didn't succeeded in latest kernels.

Comment: Do you really need the function `access_remote_vm`? While it is strange that the function is absent on x86_64 with MMU support... BTW, kernel 3.7 is not a "latest kernel", it differs slightly from 3.4 on which answer, referenced by you, is based.