# ubuntu reading a file using a loadable module

Tags: c, file, ubuntu, kernel, vfs

Hi I have a class assignment that requires me to intercept an open call then read the file and edit the output without editing the file itself this is all done in a loadable module in the kernel space. When I say editing I mean like changing the word she to _he replacing the s with an underscore it changes every instance of the word she to _he well that's the desired result. I have looked online for days trying to figure this out I thought I found a suitable example but it kept giving me an error. As soon as I enter the module into the kernel it instantly says killed then it says I cannot remove it because it is in use when it isn't this forces me to restart my virtual machine. Below is the code. Any help would be appreciated thank you.

```
 #include <linux/module.h>  // Needed by all modules
 #include <linux/kernel.h>  // Needed for KERN_INFO
 #include <linux/fs.h>      // Needed by filp
 #include <asm/uaccess.h>   // Needed by segment descriptors

 int init_module(void)
 {
  // Create variables
  struct file *f;
  char buf[128];
  mm_segment_t fs;
  int i;
  // Init the buffer with 0
  for(i=0;i<128;i++)
    buf[i] = 0;
  // To see in /var/log/messages that the module is operating
  printk(KERN_INFO "My module is loaded\n");
  // I am using Fedora and for the test I have chosen following file
 // Obviously it is much smaller than the 128 bytes, but hell with it =)
  f = filp_open("/etc/fedora-release", O_RDONLY, 0);
  if(f == NULL)
      printk(KERN_ALERT "filp_open error!!.\n");
  else{
     // Get current segment descriptor
     fs = get_fs();
     // Set segment descriptor associated to kernel space
     set_fs(get_ds());
     // Read the file
     f->f_op->read(f, buf, 128, &f->f_pos);
     // Restore segment descriptor
     set_fs(fs);
     // See what we read from file
     printk(KERN_INFO "buf:%s\n",buf);
     }
      filp_close(f,NULL);
      return 0;
     }

     void cleanup_module(void)
     {
       printk(KERN_INFO "My module is unloaded\n");
     }

     module_init(init_module);
     module_exit(cleanup_module);
```

Comment: What you need is to write sys_call hook, one for `open`, one for `read`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2103315/1212012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding reading and writing to a file from the kernel, I would suggest that you will read the following article and look into the code snippests in it:
Driving Me Nuts - Things You Never Should Do in the Kernel
Linux Journal 2005, Greg Kroah-Hartman

http://m.linuxjournal.com/article/8110