Cannot make sys_call_table read-write in Oracle 8 ARM64
Kernel version: 5.15.0-205.149.5.1.el8uek.aarch64 (All of 5.15 series)
OS: Oracle 8 ARM64
I am trying to hook into the sys_call_table, for the same I am modifying the permissions to read-write for sys_call_table. It is failing with this code (returns -22):
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
#include <linux/init.h>     // module_{init,exit}()
#include <linux/module.h>   // THIS_MODULE, MODULE_VERSION, ...
#include <linux/kernel.h>   // printk(), pr_*()
#include <linux/kallsyms.h> // kallsyms_lookup_name()
#include <asm/syscall.h>    // syscall_fn_t, __NR_*
#include <asm/ptrace.h>     // struct pt_regs
#include <asm/tlbflush.h>   // flush_tlb_kernel_range()
#include <asm/pgtable.h>    // {clear,set}_pte_bit(), set_pte()
#include <linux/vmalloc.h>  // vm_unmap_aliases()
#include <linux/mm.h>       // struct mm_struct, apply_to_page_range()
#include <linux/kconfig.h>  // IS_ENABLED()

#ifdef pr_fmt
#undef pr_fmt
#endif
#define pr_fmt(fmt) KBUILD_MODNAME ": " fmt

static struct mm_struct *init_mm_ptr;
static syscall_fn_t *syscall_table;
static syscall_fn_t original_read;

/********** HELPERS **********/

// From arch/arm64/mm/pageattr.c.
struct page_change_data {
    pgprot_t set_mask;
    pgprot_t clear_mask;
};

// From arch/arm64/mm/pageattr.c.
static int change_page_range(pte_t *ptep, unsigned long addr, void *data)
{
    struct page_change_data *cdata = data;
    pte_t pte = READ_ONCE(*ptep);

    pte = clear_pte_bit(pte, cdata->clear_mask);
    pte = set_pte_bit(pte, cdata->set_mask);

    set_pte(ptep, pte);
    return 0;
}

// From arch/arm64/mm/pageattr.c.
static int __change_memory_common(unsigned long start, unsigned long size,
                  pgprot_t set_mask, pgprot_t clear_mask)
{
    struct page_change_data data;
    int ret;

    data.set_mask = set_mask;
    data.clear_mask = clear_mask;

    ret = apply_to_page_range(init_mm_ptr, start, size, change_page_range, &data);

    flush_tlb_kernel_range(start, start + size);
    return ret;
}

// Simplified set_memory_rw() from arch/arm64/mm/pageattr.c.
static int set_page_rw(unsigned long addr)
{
    vm_unmap_aliases();    
    return __change_memory_common(addr, PAGE_SIZE, __pgprot(PTE_WRITE), __pgprot(PTE_RDONLY));
}

// Simplified set_memory_ro() from arch/arm64/mm/pageattr.c.
static int set_page_ro(unsigned long addr)
{
    vm_unmap_aliases();
    return __change_memory_common(addr, PAGE_SIZE, __pgprot(PTE_RDONLY), __pgprot(PTE_WRITE));
}

/********** ACTUAL MODULE **********/

static long myread(const struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    pr_info("read() called\n");
    return original_read(regs);
}

static int __init modinit(void)
{
    int res;

    pr_info("init\n");

    // Shouldn't fail.
    init_mm_ptr = (struct mm_struct *)kallsyms_lookup_name("init_mm");
    syscall_table = (syscall_fn_t *)kallsyms_lookup_name("sys_call_table");

    original_read = syscall_table[__NR_read];

    res = set_page_rw((unsigned long)(syscall_table + __NR_read) & PAGE_MASK);
    if (res != 0) {
        pr_err("set_page_rw() failed: %d\n", res);
        return res;
    }

    syscall_table[__NR_read] = myread;

    res = set_page_ro((unsigned long)(syscall_table + __NR_read) & PAGE_MASK);
    if (res != 0) {
        pr_err("set_page_ro() failed: %d\n", res);
        return res;
    }

    pr_info("init done\n");

    return 0;
}

static void __exit modexit(void)
{
    int res;

    pr_info("exit\n");

    res = set_page_rw((unsigned long)(syscall_table + __NR_read) & PAGE_MASK);
    if (res != 0) {
        pr_err("set_page_rw() failed: %d\n", res);
        return;
    }

    syscall_table[__NR_read] = original_read;

    res = set_page_ro((unsigned long)(syscall_table + __NR_read) & PAGE_MASK);
    if (res != 0)
        pr_err("set_page_ro() failed: %d\n", res);

    pr_info("goodbye\n");
}

module_init(modinit);
module_exit(modexit);
MODULE_VERSION("0.1");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

(Referenced from https://stackoverflow.com/a/61465861/17435873)
But the same code is working fine for kernel version 5.4.17-2136.331.7.el8uek.aarch64 (All of 5.4 series and below)
I created a kernel memory page with vmalloc. I am able to turn them read-write and read-only both with the same functions.
Code:
char *foo;

static int __init modinit(void)
{
    int res;

    pr_info("init\n");

    // Shouldn't fail.
    init_mm_ptr = (struct mm_struct *)kallsyms_lookup_name("init_mm");
    syscall_table = (syscall_fn_t *)kallsyms_lookup_name("sys_call_table");

    foo = vmalloc(PAGE_SIZE);
    res = set_page_ro((unsigned long)foo); // Returns 0 (success)
    foo[420] = '1';    // Crashed here
    res = set_page_rw((unsigned long)foo);
    foo[420] = '1';    // No crashes, set_page_rw returns 0 (success)

    pr_info("init done\n");

    return 0;
}

Update:
So I digged into these functions: apply_to_page_range, apply_to_p4d_range, apply_to_pud_range, apply_to_pmd_range, apply_to_pte_range. (Made custom functions by copying the source code for all).
Function stack:

apply_to_pmd_range
pmd_leaf    ( if (WARN_ON_ONCE(my_pmd_leaf(*pmd))) inside my_apply_to_pmd_range)
!pmd_table  ( #define pmd_leaf(pmd)  (pmd_present(pmd) && !pmd_table(pmd)) )

!pmd_table returns 1 for sys_call_table and 0 for vmalloc (only difference)
Custom func:
int my_pmd_leaf(pmd_t pmd){
    printk("inside %s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    int a1 = pmd_present(pmd), a2 = !pmd_table(pmd), a3 = a1 && a2;
    printk("a1=%d, a2=%d, a3=%d\n", a1, a2, a3);
    return a3;
}

Output:
vmalloc page
[71627.367740] inside my_pmd_leaf
[71627.369595] a1=1, a2=0, a3=0

sys_call_table
[71756.857568] inside my_pmd_leaf
[71756.859347] a1=1, a2=1, a3=1


Linux kernel for a long time has a hooking mechanism based on kprobe. Not sure why people still want to hack by modifying the syscall table.

It's only going to get more difficult in later kernel versions. For x86, the system call table no longer exists for recent kernel versions. (Actually, it does still exist, but is no longer used for executing system calls, only for tracing them.) It has been replaced with a big switch statement. I can foresee the same thing happening for arm64.

Hey there, please do not edit your post to remove all the content! It is fine as is. Even if it was answered and you found the solution you were looking for, it is still perfectly valid and can be left as is.

I ran the exact same kernel you have under QEMU and tested the module. If you take a look at the kernel log you will notice the problem quite easily:
[   31.115415] test: init
[   31.159343] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[   31.159451] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 131 at mm/memory.c:2743 apply_to_pmd_range+0xf8/0x1d0
[   31.159654] Modules linked in: test(OE+)
[   31.159974] CPU: 0 PID: 131 Comm: insmod Tainted: G           OE     5.15.0-205.149.5.1.el8uek.aarch64 #2
[   31.160186] Hardware name: linux,dummy-virt (DT)
[   31.160383] pstate: 80400005 (Nzcv daif +PAN -UAO -TCO -DIT -SSBS BTYPE=--)
[   31.160512] pc : apply_to_pmd_range+0xf8/0x1d0
[   31.160617] lr : apply_to_pmd_range+0x50/0x1d0
[   31.160754] sp : ffff80000bedba00
[   31.160867] x29: ffff80000bedba00 x28: ffff0000ffffe250 x27: ffff800009520000
[   31.161086] x26: 0000000000000000 x25: ffff80000951ffff x24: ffff80000bedbb88
[   31.161256] x23: ffff8000010f0000 x22: ffff80000ac244a8 x21: ffff80000bedbae4
[   31.161369] x20: 0000000000000001 x19: ffff800009520000 x18: 0000000000000000
[   31.161482] x17: 0000000000000000 x16: 0000000000000000 x15: 0000000000000000
[   31.161592] x14: 0000000000000000 x13: 0000000000000000 x12: 0000000000000000
[   31.161701] x11: 0000000000000000 x10: 0000000000000000 x9 : ffff80000837d010
[   31.161829] x8 : 0000000000000000 x7 : ffff80000bedbae4 x6 : 0000000000000001
[   31.161942] x5 : ffff80000bedbb88 x4 : ffff8000010f0000 x3 : 0c00000000000001
[   31.162055] x2 : ffff80000951f000 x1 : 0000000000000001 x0 : 0060000041600781
[   31.162280] Call trace:
[   31.162468]  apply_to_pmd_range+0xf8/0x1d0
[   31.162567]  apply_to_pud_range+0x9c/0x1f4
[   31.162637]  __apply_to_page_range+0xb8/0x190
[   31.162707]  apply_to_page_range+0x1c/0x44
[   31.162772]  __change_memory_common.constprop.0+0x58/0xe0 [test]
[   31.163198]  set_page_rw+0x30/0x50 [test]
[   31.163343]  modinit+0x78/0x1000 [test]
[   31.163486]  do_one_initcall+0x64/0x200
[   31.163556]  do_init_module+0x50/0x27c
[   31.163618]  load_module+0xa20/0xb70
[   31.163678]  __do_sys_init_module+0xe8/0x180
[   31.163748]  __arm64_sys_init_module+0x24/0x40
[   31.163814]  invoke_syscall+0x50/0x15c
[   31.163871]  el0_svc_common+0x48/0x144
[   31.163925]  do_el0_svc+0x30/0xe0
[   31.163976]  el0_svc+0x30/0xf0
[   31.164029]  el0t_64_sync_handler+0xc4/0x148
[   31.164091]  el0t_64_sync+0x1a4/0x1a8
[   31.164238] ---[ end trace 202353dcbe129dc1 ]---
[   31.164562] test: set_page_rw() failed: -22

The above log says that the module is hitting a warning somewhere in apply_to_pmd_range(). Looking at that function, there are only two WARN_ON_ONCE() macros there.
You are most likely triggering the WARN_ON_ONCE(pmd_leaf(*pmd)) in apply_to_pmd_range() (see here). This is because the kernel page table has the syscall table inside a huge page (it makes sense, this saves time and memory), but the __change_memory_common() function does not deal with huge pages at all. Whenever a huge mapping is encountered (pud_leaf() or pmd_leaf()) it bails out with -EINVAL.
I have re-implemented the functions to also handle the case where a huge PMD mapping is found (pmd_leaf()) by passing an additional callback function to handle leaf PMDs. I did not bother implementing the same for PUDs because there are no convenient helper functions to handle PUDs, but that is also technically doable.
Also, note that on this kernel the kallsyms_lookup_name() function is not exported, so I used the kprobes trick described here to find it at runtime.
Here's the updated code, tested on QEMU with kernel 5.15.0-205.149.5.1.el8uek.aarch64 and it seems to work fine.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
#include <linux/init.h>     // module_{init,exit}()
#include <linux/module.h>   // THIS_MODULE, MODULE_VERSION, ...
#include <linux/kernel.h>   // printk(), pr_*()
#include <linux/kallsyms.h> // kallsyms_lookup_name()
#include <asm/syscall.h>    // syscall_fn_t, __NR_*
#include <asm/ptrace.h>     // struct pt_regs
#include <asm/tlbflush.h>   // flush_tlb_kernel_range()
#include <asm/pgtable.h>    // {clear,set}_pte_bit(), set_pte()
#include <linux/vmalloc.h>  // vm_unmap_aliases()
#include <linux/mm.h>       // struct mm_struct, apply_to_page_range()
#include <linux/kprobes.h>  // register_kprobe(), unregister_kprobe()


#ifdef pr_fmt
#undef pr_fmt
#endif
#define pr_fmt(fmt) KBUILD_MODNAME ": " fmt

typedef unsigned long (*kallsyms_lookup_name_t)(const char *);

static struct mm_struct *init_mm_ptr;
static syscall_fn_t *syscall_table;
static syscall_fn_t original_read;

/***** HELPERS ****************************************************************/

/**
 * This is an enhanced implementation of __apply_to_page_range() that is also
 * capable of handling huge PMD mappings (pmd_leaf()). The original
 * implementation of __apply_to_page_range() only handles last-level PTEs, and
 * fails with -EINVAL for PMD mappings. This implementation takes 2 function
 * pointers instead of a single one:
 *
 *   - pte_fn_t fn_pte: function to apply changes to a leaf PTE
 *   - pmd_fn_t fn_pmd: function to apply changes to a leaf PMD
 */

// pte_fn_t already present in <linux/mm.h>
typedef int (*pmd_fn_t)(pmd_t *pmd, unsigned long addr, void *data);

// From arch/arm64/mm/hugetlbpage.c
int pmd_huge(pmd_t pmd)
{
    return pmd_val(pmd) && !(pmd_val(pmd) & PMD_TABLE_BIT);
}

// Adapted from arch/arm64/mm/hugetlbpage.c
int pud_huge(pud_t pud)
{
#if CONFIG_PGTABLE_LEVELS == 2
    return 0;
#else
    return pud_val(pud) && !(pud_val(pud) & PUD_TABLE_BIT);
#endif
}

// From arch/arm64/mm/pageattr.c.
struct page_change_data {
    pgprot_t set_mask;
    pgprot_t clear_mask;
};

// From arch/arm64/mm/pageattr.c.
static int change_page_range(pte_t *ptep, unsigned long addr, void *data)
{
    struct page_change_data *cdata = data;
    pte_t pte = READ_ONCE(*ptep);

    pte = clear_pte_bit(pte, cdata->clear_mask);
    pte = set_pte_bit(pte, cdata->set_mask);

    set_pte(ptep, pte);
    return 0;
}

static int change_pmd_range(pmd_t *pmdp, unsigned long addr, void *data)
{
    struct page_change_data *cdata = data;
    pmd_t pmd = READ_ONCE(*pmdp);

    pmd = clear_pmd_bit(pmd, cdata->clear_mask);
    pmd = set_pmd_bit(pmd, cdata->set_mask);

    set_pmd(pmdp, pmd);
    return 0;
}


// Adapted from mm/memory.c
static int apply_to_pte_range(struct mm_struct *mm, pmd_t *pmd,
                     unsigned long addr, unsigned long end,
                     pte_fn_t fn, void *data,
                     pgtbl_mod_mask *mask)
{
    pte_t *pte, *mapped_pte;
    int err = 0;
    spinlock_t *ptl;


    mapped_pte = pte = (mm == init_mm_ptr) ? pte_offset_kernel(pmd, addr) :
        pte_offset_map_lock(mm, pmd, addr, &ptl);

    BUG_ON(pmd_huge(*pmd));
    arch_enter_lazy_mmu_mode();

    if (fn) {
        do {
            if (!pte_none(*pte)) {
                err = fn(pte++, addr, data);
                if (err)
                    break;
            }
        } while (addr += PAGE_SIZE, addr != end);
    }
    *mask |= PGTBL_PTE_MODIFIED;

    arch_leave_lazy_mmu_mode();

    if (mm != init_mm_ptr)
        pte_unmap_unlock(mapped_pte, ptl);
    return err;
}

// Adapted from mm/memory.c
static int apply_to_pmd_range(struct mm_struct *mm, pud_t *pud,
                unsigned long addr, unsigned long end,
                pte_fn_t fn_pte, pmd_fn_t fn_pmd,
                void *data, pgtbl_mod_mask *mask)
{
    pmd_t *pmd;
    unsigned long next;
    int err = 0;

    BUG_ON(pud_huge(*pud));

    pmd = pmd_offset(pud, addr);
    do {
        next = pmd_addr_end(addr, end);
        if (pmd_none(*pmd))
            continue;

        if (pmd_leaf(*pmd)) {
            if (!fn_pmd || pmd_none(*pmd))
                continue;

            err = fn_pmd(pmd, addr, data);
            if (err)
                break;
        } else {
            if (!pmd_none(*pmd) && WARN_ON_ONCE(pmd_bad(*pmd)))
                continue;

            err = apply_to_pte_range(mm, pmd, addr, next, fn_pte,
                data, mask);
            if (err)
                break;
        }
    } while (pmd++, addr = next, addr != end);

    return err;
}

// Adapted from mm/memory.c
static int apply_to_pud_range(struct mm_struct *mm, p4d_t *p4d,
                unsigned long addr, unsigned long end,
                pte_fn_t fn_pte, pmd_fn_t fn_pmd,
                void *data, pgtbl_mod_mask *mask)
{
    pud_t *pud;
    unsigned long next;
    int err = 0;

    pud = pud_offset(p4d, addr);
    do {
        next = pud_addr_end(addr, end);
        if (pud_none(*pud))
            continue;
        if (WARN_ON_ONCE(pud_leaf(*pud)))
            return -EINVAL;
        if (!pud_none(*pud) && WARN_ON_ONCE(pud_bad(*pud)))
            continue;
        err = apply_to_pmd_range(mm, pud, addr, next, fn_pte,
            fn_pmd, data, mask);
        if (err)
            break;
    } while (pud++, addr = next, addr != end);

    return err;
}

// Adapted from mm/memory.c
static int apply_to_p4d_range(struct mm_struct *mm, pgd_t *pgd,
                unsigned long addr, unsigned long end,
                pte_fn_t fn_pte, pmd_fn_t fn_pmd,
                void *data, pgtbl_mod_mask *mask)
{
    p4d_t *p4d;
    unsigned long next;
    int err = 0;

    p4d = p4d_offset(pgd, addr);
    do {
        next = p4d_addr_end(addr, end);
        if (p4d_none(*p4d))
            continue;
        if (WARN_ON_ONCE(p4d_leaf(*p4d)))
            return -EINVAL;
        if (!p4d_none(*p4d) && WARN_ON_ONCE(p4d_bad(*p4d)))
            continue;
        err = apply_to_pud_range(mm, p4d, addr, next, fn_pte, fn_pmd,
            data, mask);
        if (err)
            break;
    } while (p4d++, addr = next, addr != end);

    return err;
}

// Adapted from mm/memory.c
static int __apply_to_page_range(struct mm_struct *mm, unsigned long addr,
                 unsigned long size,
                 pte_fn_t fn_pte, pmd_fn_t fn_pmd,
                 void *data)
{
    pgd_t *pgd;
    unsigned long start = addr, next;
    unsigned long end = addr + size;
    pgtbl_mod_mask mask = 0;
    int err = 0;

    if (WARN_ON(addr >= end))
        return -EINVAL;

    pgd = pgd_offset(mm, addr);
    do {
        next = pgd_addr_end(addr, end);
        if (pgd_none(*pgd))
            continue;
        if (WARN_ON_ONCE(pgd_leaf(*pgd)))
            return -EINVAL;
        if (!pgd_none(*pgd) && WARN_ON_ONCE(pgd_bad(*pgd)))
            continue;
        err = apply_to_p4d_range(mm, pgd, addr, next, fn_pte, fn_pmd,
            data, &mask);
        if (err)
            break;
    } while (pgd++, addr = next, addr != end);

    if (mask & ARCH_PAGE_TABLE_SYNC_MASK)
        arch_sync_kernel_mappings(start, start + size);

    return err;
}

// Adapted from arch/arm64/mm/pageattr.c.
static int __change_memory_common(unsigned long start, unsigned long size,
                  pgprot_t set_mask, pgprot_t clear_mask)
{
    struct page_change_data data;
    int ret;

    data.set_mask = set_mask;
    data.clear_mask = clear_mask;

    ret = __apply_to_page_range(init_mm_ptr, start, size,
        &change_page_range, &change_pmd_range, &data);
    if (ret)
        pr_info("__apply_to_page_range() failed: %d\n", ret);

    flush_tlb_kernel_range(start, start + size);
    return ret;
}

// Simplified version of set_memory_rw() from arch/arm64/mm/pageattr.c.
static int set_page_rw(unsigned long addr)
{
    vm_unmap_aliases();
    return __change_memory_common(addr, PAGE_SIZE, __pgprot(PTE_WRITE), __pgprot(PTE_RDONLY));
}

// Simplified version of set_memory_ro() from arch/arm64/mm/pageattr.c.
static int set_page_ro(unsigned long addr)
{
    vm_unmap_aliases();
    return __change_memory_common(addr, PAGE_SIZE, __pgprot(PTE_RDONLY), __pgprot(PTE_WRITE));
}

/***** ACTUAL MODULE **********************************************************/

static long myread(const struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    pr_info("read() called\n");
    return original_read(regs);
}

static int __init modinit(void)
{
    struct kprobe kp = { .symbol_name = "kallsyms_lookup_name" };
    kallsyms_lookup_name_t kallsyms_lookup_name;
    int res;

    pr_info("init\n");

    // Workaround for kallsyms_lookup_name() not being exported: find it
    // using kprobes.
    res = register_kprobe(&kp);
    if (res != 0) {
        pr_err("register_kprobe() failed: %d\n", res);
        return res;
    }

    kallsyms_lookup_name = (kallsyms_lookup_name_t)kp.addr;
    unregister_kprobe(&kp);

    init_mm_ptr = (struct mm_struct *)kallsyms_lookup_name("init_mm");
    if (!init_mm_ptr) {
        pr_err("init_mm not found\n");
        return -ENOSYS;
    }

    syscall_table = (syscall_fn_t *)kallsyms_lookup_name("sys_call_table");
    if (!syscall_table) {
        pr_err("sys_call_table not found\n");
        return -ENOSYS;
    }

    original_read = syscall_table[__NR_read];

    res = set_page_rw((unsigned long)(syscall_table + __NR_read) & PAGE_MASK);
    if (res != 0) {
        pr_err("set_page_rw() failed: %d\n", res);
        return res;
    }

    syscall_table[__NR_read] = myread;

    res = set_page_ro((unsigned long)(syscall_table + __NR_read) & PAGE_MASK);
    if (res != 0) {
        pr_err("set_page_ro() failed: %d\n", res);
        return res;
    }

    pr_info("init done\n");

    return 0;
}

static void __exit modexit(void)
{
    int res;

    pr_info("exit\n");

    res = set_page_rw((unsigned long)(syscall_table + __NR_read) & PAGE_MASK);
    if (res != 0) {
        pr_err("set_page_rw() failed: %d\n", res);
        return;
    }

    syscall_table[__NR_read] = original_read;

    res = set_page_ro((unsigned long)(syscall_table + __NR_read) & PAGE_MASK);
    if (res != 0)
        pr_err("set_page_ro() failed: %d\n", res);

    pr_info("goodbye\n");
}

module_init(modinit);
module_exit(modexit);
MODULE_VERSION("0.1");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Marco Bonelli");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Syscall hijack on arm64.");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

