# Is it necessary to call set_memory_rw after disabling CR0 "Write Protect" to modify read only pages in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel

Consider the following question on Stack Overflow on system call hooking by modifying the `sys_call_table`.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103315/linux-kernel-system-call-hooking-example

Since CR0 "Write Protect" (bit 16) controls whether it's possible for the kernel to write to read-only pages, why does some  code then calls `set_memory_rw` to set the permissions for the target pages to RW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The `CR0.WP` method disables write protect support *globally*, whereas the `set_memory_rw` method merely adds the write bit to specific pages. If you have already disabled write protection through the control register, then there is no need to do anything else. All kernel memory will be globally writable from within the kernel until you re-enable write protection through the same register.

Make sure you [disable interrupts](http://vulnfactory.org/blog/2011/08/12/wp-safe-or-not/) before writing to `CR0`, then re-enable them afterwards.